# Looping through array logic

Tags: javascript, loops

How does the below logic at line `if(!chars[word])` work?

Suppose we have an string that we need to find count of words.

```js
const str = "hello                               world Welcome to hello world"
const chars = {}
const arr = str.split('')
for (let word of arr) {
  if (!chars[word]) {
    chars[word] = 1
  } else {
    chars[word]++
  }
}

console.log(chars)
```

I want to know how it exactly works like how it finds the number of count.

Answer (score 0):

first, if you wanna count words then I think you meant to write

```
const arr = str.split(' ') // split the string based on spaces
```

`for (let word of arr)` is simply iterating through each word.
`if (!chars[word])` means if `chars[word]` is undefined (the object `chars` doesn't have an attribute equal to the word), if ***YES*** `chars[word] = 1` creates an attribute with the word and set the value to 1, if ***NO*** (an attribute already exists) then `chars[word]++` simply increment the value

Answer (score 0):

You may be wondering about the chars object itself since it isn’t an array.

In JavaScript an object literal can be accessed like an array.

```
chars[“h”]
```

Is the same as

```
chars.h
```

If the property doesn’t exist, the code creates it and sets it to one. If it does exist, it increments the value.

Answer (score -1):

You should have worked through it on paper.

---

You said you wanted to count words. But you're splitting into individual characters, not words. I presume you meant to use `str.split(' ')`, and I'll explain as if this fix was applied.

---

The first time through the loop, `word` is `hello`.

`chars[word]` is `undefined`, since `chars` has no element with key `hello`.

`undefined` is a false value, so we perform `chars[word] = 1`, setting the count for `hello` to `1`.

---

In a later pass, `word` is `hello` again.

`chars[word]` is `1` this time, since we set it to `1` earlier.

`1` is a true value, so we perform `chars[word]++`, setting the count for `hello` to `2`.